# Number of $k$-polygons in an $n$ side-polygon with at least p points between vertexes

Tags: combinatorics

I'm not sure the title is perfectly clear so I'll try to explain it. We have $n$-polygon.We now want to create $k$-polygon whose vertexes are those of the $n$ polygon but such as there is at least $p$ vertexes between every vertex of $k$-polygon (hope this makes sense)

Here's what I've done

We can look at this as the sequence of length $n$ composed of $0$ and $1$ such as there is exactly $k$ ones and there is at least $p$ zeroes between each two ones and after the last one. if we take $p$ zeroes from each of those spots we get a sequence of $0$ and $1$ with exactly k zeroes. So the number we're looking for is the same as the number of binary sequences of length $n-kp$ with exactly $k$ ones which is ${n-kp \choose k}$

Then I drew some examples and if we want to create a triangle in the $9$-polygon such as there is at least 2 vertexes between every vertex of triangle  we can do it in 3 different ways which is not the same answer I get when I plug it in the formula above.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does every point(vertex) is unique ? Hope you understand meaning of unique in combinatorics

Comment: Yeah every point is uniqe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re missing a factor $\frac n{n-kp}$ that arises because $n$ cyclic permutations of the full configurations are being mapped to just $n-kp$ cyclic permutations of the reduced configurations. You call the configurations “sequences”, but in order to turn them into linear sequences, you’d have to mark a vertex at which to split the cycle, and there are $n$ choices for that vertex in the full configurations and only $n-kp$ choices in the reduced ones. Correcting for this yields the count

$$\frac n{n-kp}\binom{n-kp}k\;,$$

which is indeed $3$ in your example.